# Getting aborted error when scanning a polynomial structure

Tags: c++, class

I wrote a little class for polynomials, which saves a degree n, and a vector corresponding to the coefficients of my polynomial. I also wrote a function to get an input from the user, so that the program creates a polynomial with the degree you put in and the corresponding coefficients. Here is the simple class:

```
class Polynomial {
    int n;
    double* coeff;
```

and my constructor/destructor and the scan function:

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(int n)
{
    assert(n >= 0);
    this->n = n;
    coeff = new double[(n + 1)];
}

void Polynomial::SetCoeff(int n, double x)
{
    coeff[n] = x;
}



Polynomial::~Polynomial()
{
    if(n>0) delete[] coeff;
}


Polynomial& ScanPoly()
{
    int n = 0;
    cout << "n= ";
    cin >> n;
    double x = 0;

    Polynomial* poly = new Polynomial(n);

    for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << "a_" << i << "= ";
        cin >> x;
        (*poly).SetCoeff(i, x); //Error occurs here
    }
    return (*poly);
}
```

When I call the ScanPoly() function, I get an "Aborted" error at the end of the for loop, when i reaches its lowest value. I tried changing the range of i, making it stop at 1, but this did not help. At first, I thought that my vector is not large enough, but that does not seem to be the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Returning a reference to a heap-allocated instance with no other ownership on it is sending shivers down my spine. Please don't do that.

Comment: Add the `SetCoeff` code, it might be wrong.

Comment: @Frank .. Uh oh... Im sorry for that... I was afraid that someone would say that, because to be honest... I did not think it was a good idea either. Unfortunately, I was not quite sure how else I should do it, Can I just return the object itself, instead of the reference?

Comment: Yes, return an object (but don't `new` it, that is a recipe for trouble.)

Comment: @M3xr What you "should" do, ideally, is use `std::vector<double>` instead of `double*` for `coeff`, create `poly` on the stack instead of the heap, and return that. As a minimal change, you should just return a `Polynomial*` instead. If you return a Polynomial by value with the current implementation, you would need to add a copy constructor to your class.

Comment: @juanchopanza His class (most likely) doesn't have a copy/move constructor and handles resources as raw pointers. That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Frank A good opportunity to learn to write unbroken classes.

Comment: @Frank actually, I did write a copy constructor (just for learning purposes. )Your approach did fix my problem, thank you very much for that. What just confused me is: I thought I had to "new" it into the heap, because I thought once I return the function, my object will otherwise get destroyed, even with a copy constructor in place.

Comment: Remove the `if(n>0)` from the destructor: you always allocate the array `coeff`, even if `n` is zero.

Comment: Hm - although I agree that the code lacks a copy constructor, I do not understand why the program aborts. `ScanPoly` allocates a new object on the heap, and this object isn't destroyed anywhere. So the default copy constructor should have - besides copying 'n' by value - also having copied the pointer `coeff` by value, which then still points to a valid memory, right?